# Opening MP3 files with text editors

Tags: python-2.7, mp3, text-editor

I have a question:

When I open an mp3 file with a text editor(sublime text), a few hundred thousand numbers in 4 digits appear(like picture below).

[image]

I got curious and experimented, deleting sections of the file and playing the mp3 file.

When I deleted the first parts, the music played but the file's CD artwork disappeared. When I deleted a huge chunk of the middle section, the music played but was shortened, with the middle part of the song gone.

Do you know what each part of the picture-letter combination represents?

I want to manipulate mp3 files(slow them down, lower the pitch, etc.) with python by modifying these numbers.

Do you have any insight on this, or what I can google to further explore?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This are hex values and represents how the bytes in you mp3 are laid out in memory. To manipulate them you can think of some ideas of your own for example if you just want to slow the mp3 down you can just copy each hex value and repeat them adjacent to each other. This will result in program reading the same value for a longer time and thus slowing down the tempo. The more copies you make the slower the music will play. Making the music fast requires deleting alternate bytes. Likewise you can think of more ways to manipulate these hex values. For example you can add echo, cancel noise in an audio however I don't know how that's done.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at an MP3 file structure specification. Each MP3 file is composed of multiple frames and tags. Those hex values you are looking at hold the content for each frame. Modifying each frame will allow you to adjust the sampling rate and bitrate.

For more in-depth information on the MP3 specification, I would take a look at

http://www.multiweb.cz/twoinches/mp3inside.htm